# Reading Node.js Heap Snapshots (created via Nodetime) -- why are my objects not GC'd?

Tags: node.js

I'm having some surprising results in my Nodetime heap snapshot:

[image]

Am I reading this right that there are 1706 instances of a "user" in my heap? This seems absurdly high, I'm not even quite sure how I would have allocated that many. In any case, are there any tips / tricks / hints to find out why these are hanging around? I've already used JSHint on my code to ensure there are no free globals being allocated. Everything should be wrapped in the closure scope of the request... so why aren't the users, posts, etc. being garbage collected when the request finishes? Here's some (redacted) code to show how I'm doing things...

What's very surprising is that **I took the above heap snapshot about 10m after the last API call finished**. So, those objects were all hanging around for long after the requests which triggered them to be allocated was finished!

code:

```
var User = require('./user').User,
    Q = require('q');

// this function is called via express' router, eg when the client visits myapi.com/users/zane
function getUser(req, res, next)
{
   var user = extend({},User).initialize();

   Q.ncall(user.model.find, user.model, {'username': req.arguments[0]})
   .then(function(data){
       res.writeHead(200, {});
       res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
   })
   .fail(next).end();
}
```

And the "User" module looks something like this:

```
exports.User = extend({}, {
    initialize: function() {
        var Schema = api.mongoose.Schema;
        this.schema = new Schema({
            'username': {'type':String, 'index':true}
        });
        this.model = api.db.model('users', this.schema);
    }

    // ... some other helper functions in here
});
```

Based upon my express code, above, I'd expect the lifespan of the user object which is allocated to be only as long as the request takes to return. Am I missing some key Node.js GC idea here?

Comment: `.then(function(data){
       user = null;
       res.writeHead(200, {});`  You can set your objects to null to clean them up.  (sry hit enter when I ment to hit shift-enter)

Comment: That makes sense, to a degree... but isn't the point of node / javascript etc. to avoid this manual level of memory management...? Going through every line of my node and null'ing all objects when I'm done with them seems like an unlikely & odd solution.

Comment: The point is for the most part you don't have to, and even in this case the GC might get all the users when it gets more aggressive.  But by using `object = null;` you still retain the ability to clean up efficiently where it's important.

Comment: because you see 'user' property in the heap snapshot means that 'user' and 'posts' properties are in the heap, i.e. are part of objects and not closure scope variables. This might give you a hint of what might be leaking. Do you see any correlation of 'user' or 'posts' property count with users in db, calls made, etc.?

Comment: The "posts" as well as that long hex-string property are both objects which get placed onto the User class. In the code example above, we would have something like user.posts = [ ... ]; after the user.model.find call. But, because the user object should be GC'd by the function closure, shouldn't the user.posts object also be GC'd?

Comment: @DmitriMelikyan - you said "are part of objects and not closure scope variables." Could you elaborate on this, eg, what would cause this to be the case? My understanding that any object/var created within a function closure is within the closure scope. Are you saying I accidentally allocated outside this scope? It makes sense that "posts" is a property on an object, but the OBJECT should be in closure scope, and the whole thing should be GC'd... or so I thought.

Comment: the objects are not in closure scope, only retainers, e.g. variables can be. If the closure is out of scope the object will lose reference and will be GC'd unless nothing else is referencing it. In your case it seems that they are referenced somewhere else. Are the counts of objects only increasing over time?

Comment: Hm, I guess I'm not understanding this idea of "the closure out of scope." In any case, I just did some quick testing: I started the server and then made a single API call to the node server. The "posts" property had a count of 9 and a size of 1350Kb. Refreshing the same API call a few times, the size changed but the count stayed the same. In general, the counts on these objects (users, posts, etc.) seem to fluctuate, but not exceed a certain number...

Answer (score 2):

This line looks suspiciously inefficient:

```
var user = extend({},User).initialize();
```

I'm assuming the `extend` call copies the `User` object and then calls its `initialize` method.  Why are you copying the `User` object on each API invocation?

Then in the `initialize` call you create a new Mongoose schema object and then register it as a model via the `api.db.model` call.  Wouldn't it be better to create the schema once and register it during initialization?

The combination of both of these may be resulting in more objects being created on each call than necessary, and I bet those registered Mongoose models do not GC easily.

Comment: I was not keen on this method, either, but I got it from this site: https://npmjs.org/package/pd

Good point about the models, though.

Comment: @ZaneClaes You're misusing the `extend` concept here as you're not adding any methods or properties to `User`, you're just copying it and adding overhead.

Comment: Well, in the omitted functions within the "User" class, I need to store instance-specific data. Eg, this.data = 'mydata'; within one of the omitted functions. In other words, I was trying to instantiate an instance of the User class, but new User().initialize(); does not work :( As I review this, though, clearly I'm doing something wrong... I just don't know how to do it right